# JS wait for content to finish loading before running function

Tags: javascript

I'm running a webpage in some graphics playout software. The function `update()` is automatically called by the graphics software when the page initially loads up, however I need to wait for the animation library to finish loading before the code in `update()` executes.

```js
animation.addEventListener('DOMLoaded', function () {
  console.log('Animation ready');
});

// This is automatically called by the graphics renderer on page load.
function update(data) {
  // update the data in the animation...
};
```

I've come up with a workaround using `setInterval` that check if the animation has loaded before running the update code:

```js
var animationLoaded = false;
animation.addEventListener('DOMLoaded', function() {
  console.log('Animation ready');
  animationLoaded = true;
});

// This is automatically called by the graphics renderer on page load.
function update(data) {
  var updateInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (animationLoaded) {
      clearInterval(updateInterval);
      // update the data in the animation...
    }
  }, 10);
}
```

I feel there is a much better way of doing this, maybe using async/await? but I am unsure how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea, may not be the best :

- on the `update` function, if `DOMLoaded` has been trigger then do your job, else save the `data` parameter
- on the `DOMLoaded` function, call `update` with the saved datas (if set)

```
var animationLoaded = false;
var animationData = null;

animation.addEventListener('DOMLoaded', function() {
  animationLoaded = true;
  if (animationData !== null) {
    update(animationData);
  }
});

// This is automatically called by the graphics renderer on page load.
function update(data) {
  if (animationLoaded) {
    // update the data in the animation...
  } else {
    animationData = data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've ended up doing it like this. As you say it may not be the best, but it works and it's better than what I had!